# Generating a number between a given range and 0

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a random number between a given range and 0.
The code given below helped me to generate a number between the given range.

```
(int)(Math.random() * 13 + 4);
```

Is it possible to modify this code to generate a value between 4 and 10 and also 0

Comment: The question hasn't a real answer in the linked page: it doesn't want a random number in a range but a random number in a range *plus* a value outside that range.

Answer (score 1):

use this for generate a value between 4 and 10

```
 public static double getRandomDoubleBetweenRange(int 4, int 10){
    double x = (Math.random()*((10-4)+1))+4;
    return x;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a homework question so I won't spoonfeed you with the correct answer but give you the tools you need to answer it yourself:

> public static double random()
>
> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to
>   0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--

Casting a double to an int performs a narrowing primitive conversion. In the range you use and for positive numbers, you can just treat it like a floor (removing the numbers after the decimal point).

If you want to know about the details, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the cause.

```
//stream 3 random numbers from 0 to 10 and pick any of them
int random = new Random().ints(3, 0, 11).findAny().getAsInt(); 
//print it
System.out.println(random);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
// make a list of 0 and 4-10
 List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
 // used for picking random number from within a list
 Random random = new SecureRandom();
 // get random index element from a list
 int randomNumber = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
 // print
 System.out.println(randomNumber);
```

Comment: It is not an answer for that question

Comment: Dziekuje for notification, @Rafał Sokalski .His Q. has been edited. I will update it.